# why does SVN checkout throw 175002 error?

Tags: svn, netbeans, svn-checkout

while trying to checkout a project via svn i get the error: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E175002: unknown host
E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/CNSS_Project'.

Any help? thank !

Answer (score 1):

The error is "unknown host". This error means that the client is unable to resolve the server hostname entered in the URL because it is unknown on the DNS that you use. You need to contact the system administrator for assistance with this issue.

Please also note that you can enter the server's IP address in the URL to workaround the issue.